# spring boot autowired repository in Hibernate interceptor not working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Hibernate interceptor to act on an update and need Repository to save in database.

I autowired repository and it's not working. Always null. Here is my code :

```
@Component
public class AuditInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

@Autowired
private LogsRepository repository;

public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    if(entity instanceof Personnel) {
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
            if(currentState[i] != previousState[i]) {
                Log log = new Log();
                log.setEntity("Personnel");
                log.setIdEntity(id.toString());
                log.setPropertyChanged(propertyNames[i] );
                log.setOldValue(previousState[i]  != null ? previousState[i].toString() : "");
                log.setNewValue(currentState[i] != null ? currentState[i].toString() : "");
                log.setTimestamp(new Date());
                System.out.println(log.toString());
                repository.save(log);
                return true;
            }
            System.out.println("Property names :"+propertyNames[i]);
            System.out.println("Old value :"+previousState[i]);
            System.out.println("New value :"+currentState[i]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Interceptor works fine but LogRepository is always null.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by implementing ApplicationContextAware

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T extends Object> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
LogsRepository repository = SpringContext.getBean(LogsRepository.class);
```